# Create n matrice in a range with python

Tags: python, matrix, range

Hello I am new to python and I need to create n matrix with each a different content inside, and I want to be able to store the matrices with each one a different name T1, T2, ... Tn to return them, example of what i am expecting [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPpwt.png) Thanks for your help !

Comment: I suggest you should use a dictionary. You can store values in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this piece of code

````
def matrix(n):
    mat={}
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        mat.update({f"T{i}":[i for j in range(n)]}) #== You can also insert a number in the ```range()``` for specific number of the digits
    return mat
print(matrix(5))
````

Comment: Thanks you a lot !

Comment: Welcome @MatthieuSerra. If this answer is complete, please mark it as complete.

Comment: How do i do this ? :s

Comment: Just press on the tick button next to the answer @MatthieuSerra

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with some randomly selected variables (matrix shape, number of matrices):

```py
import numpy as np

matrix_shape = (10, 10)
n = 10

matrix_dict = {f'T_{i}': np.ones(matrix_shape) * i for i in range(1, n)}
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot !